# WCF Publishing Service - How to publish multiple Web Methods and Web Operations at the same time?

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I consumed a web service from a Provider, it includes 100 operations (two ways request and response). I deployed a BizTalk project on a BizTalk Server including the schemas (without mapping, orchestration, etc.). After this I imported the binding config files that were generated by Visual Studio when consuming the WCF web service.

Now, I want to publish BizTalk Receive Location through WCF-WSHttp or WCF-BasicHttp. As I said, I don't use Orchestrations, so I will import by Schema and the step "WCF Services" I have to select more than 100 times to configure this step.

Does anyone have a solution to solve this case?

Comment: please add some more tags

Comment: I don't know an easy way, but you have to do this only once (Unless you'll change anything). BTW do you really need 100 different operations? Probably you can use some canonical schema with some context properties for routing?

Answer (score 0):

You could use powershell.

```
[void] 

[System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM")
$server = "."
$connectionString = "SERVER=" + $server + ";DATABASE=BizTalkMgmtDb;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$Catalog = New-Object Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM.BtsCatalogExplorer
$Catalog.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$app = $Catalog.AddNewApplication()
$rcvPort = $app.AddNewReceivePort(0)
for($i=1 
     $i -le 100
     $i++)
{
$rcvLocation = $rcvPort.AddNewReceiveLocation()
$rcvLocation.Name = 'what ever name you choose'
...
...
$rcvLocation.TransportTypeData = "<> ... THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT SVC DESCRIPTION <>"

}
```

There are a bunch of other properties that you will have to set before you can actually use it.